# How can I open security settings and scroll the activity down in security settings programmatically?

Tags: android

I want to open the security settings then scroll down the activity of security programmatically. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Before someone can answer you how to scroll down the activity, you can at least use `startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS));` to open the Security Settings activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a straightforward task but I believe it may be possible using a similar implementation to [Robotium](https://github.com/jayway/robotium/).

I believe the key is using the ActivityMonitor class and a service to send events to an activity launched by another activity. This should put you on the right path. You can look at the ActivityUtils.java class to see an example of how to instantiate the ActivityMonitor. You could likely copy in parts of the Robotium code and use it for launching the Settings and causing a scroll event to occur.